# Extract the last two strings of words separated by the last comma

Tags: r, regex

Consider the the data frame `df` which contains the column `location`.

```
df <- structure(
  list(location = c("International Society for Horticultural Science (ISHS), Leuven, Belgium",
                    "International Society for Horticultural Science (ISHS), Leuven, Belgium",
                    "White House, Jodhpur, India", "Crop Science Society of the Philippines, College, Philippines",
                    "Crop Science Society of the Philippines, College, Philippines",
                    "Institute of Forest Science, Kangwon National University, Kangwon, Korea Republic")), 
  .Names = "location", 
  row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
  class = "data.frame")
```

I was trying to extract the `address` from `location`. The `address` should contain the string of words that are separated by the last comma. How do I do this? I have been trying to learn regular expressions but my knowledge is not up to par. Here is what I tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(address = str_extract(location, "[:alpha:]+$")) %>% select(address)
```

This outputs

```
#       address
# 1     Belgium
# 2     Belgium
# 3       India
# 4 Philippines
# 5 Philippines
# 6    Republic
```

Here is my desired output:

```
#                   address
# 1         Leuven, Belgium
# 2         Leuven, Belgium
# 3          Jodhpur, India
# 4    College, Philippines
# 5    College, Philippines
# 6 Kangwon, Korea Republic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[a-z A-Z]+, [a-z A-Z]+$
```

This might work

Comment: You are a rock star. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Like you even my knowledge of regex is not up to par. So after trying to find out different ways to do it in regex, I gave up and use the traditional approach.

```
sapply(strsplit(df$location, ","), function(x) paste0(tail(x, 2), collapse = ","))

#[1] " Leuven, Belgium"         " Leuven, Belgium"        
#[3] " Jodhpur, India"          " College, Philippines"   
#[5] " College, Philippines"    " Kangwon, Korea Republic"
```

Here we split `location` on "," and select the last two instances using `tail` and `paste` them together with "," again to get the required output.

---

And I finally got some time to get the regex thing working.

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract(df$location, regex = "[^,]+,[^,]+$")

#[1] " Leuven, Belgium"         " Leuven, Belgium"        
#[3] " Jodhpur, India"          " College, Philippines"   
#[5] " College, Philippines"    " Kangwon, Korea Republic"
```

Comment: A regex varation to get rid of the leading spaces: `"[^,\\s][^,]*,[^,]+$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ahh..That makes the output look better. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
df %>%
  mutate(address = str_extract(location, "([[:alpha:]]+ ?)+, ([[:alpha:]]+ ?)+$"))
```

The pattern `[[:alpha:]]+ ?` matches a string of letters, possibly followed by a space.  Wrapping it in parenthesis followed by a + to look for that entire pattern showing up at least one time.

Comment: I think this is what `[a-z A-Z]+, [a-z A-Z]+$` does.

Comment: The only difference is that my solution specifically does not allow a space as the first character.  If you notice, using that expression adds a space at the beginning of each address entry.